# Consume WCF service using add web reference and add a soap header

Tags: wcf, soap, asmx, soapheader, web-reference

I have a WCF 4 web service that checks for a soap header. This works fine with a WCF client but I have a customer that needs to use the old web reference from their app. How do you consume a WCF service using Add Web Reference and the add a SOAP header in the client? Lets keep it simple and say I want to pass a country in a header, so the header name will be country.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your endpoint across the basicHttpBinding in order to interoperate with pre .net 3.0 clients.

**UPDATE**

Does this help? http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2007/04/27/wcf-building-an-http-user-agent-message-inspector.aspx

Comment: Yes, its basic http. I just can't see how to add a header.

Comment: Hugh, this works when everything is WCF. I am trying to add a header to a proxy that has veen created using "Add Web reference" where the .Net client cannot use WCF. What happened is one of our customers has a 3rd party app that can only consume asmx services, or that is what they tell me.