# how to send soap header when consuming an wcf service from an asmx service

Tags: wcf, soap, header

I have an ASMX service and I am consuming a WCF service that is added by "Add Web Reference". The proxy thus generated does not have the headers exposed. I need to send headers as part of the request to that WCF service call.

How can I do it ?

Comment: I saw a similar post here but it is not answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581831/consume-wcf-service-using-add-web-reference-and-add-a-soap-header

Comment: the question is not clear. can you consume wcf in a consoel app and the problem is just in asmx context or is it a general problem with consuming this service?